# Flex: Displaying xml in advanced data grid

Tags: xml, apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

I have an external xml file and i want to display it in an advanced data grid....as in if i click the parent element the children have to be displayed in the corresponding columns...i'm trying it with my dataprovider but its not working.
How do i do that?...

Comment: Are you accessing the field names correctly (datafield="@yourField"), and have you using the HierarchicalData class for you XML?

Comment: Maybe provide some code?

Comment: @adam..i have done all that
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid width="529" height="348" 
 dataProvider="{new HierarchicalData(xmlList)}">
     <mx:columns>
     <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@pid" headerText="PARENT"/>
       <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@uid" headerText="USER ID"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

Comment: and my resultEvent function is....
public function results(event:ResultEvent):void
   {
    xmlList=user.lastResult.users;
}

here user is my HTTPService id  and users is my root element..

Comment: and this is my xml file....saved user.xml
 <users>
            <PARENT pid="12345">
                <userid uid="aaaa"/>
                <userid uid="bbbb" /> 
            </PARENT>
            <PARENT pid="54321">
                <userid uid="cccc" />
            </PARENT>
            </users>

Comment: " (datafield="@yourField") this is what caught me up once this was in it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are coding as usual:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{user.users}" width="100%" height="100%">
...
...
</mx:columns>
```

So may you change a little?

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{new HierarchicalData(user.users)}" width="100%" height="100%">
...
...
</mx:columns>
```